# Error "no change" when using golang-migrate and docker postgres

Tags: go, golang-migrate

I've a golang project.

Below is the `main.go` file -

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
    dbmigration "github.com/rajcspsg/grpc-ms/unary/server/db"
)

func main() {

    sqlDB, err := sql.Open("pgx", "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/grpc?sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Can't connect to database: ", err)
    }

    dbmigration.Migrate(sqlDB)
}
```

`dbmigration.go` is -

```golang
package dbmigration

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
)

func Migrate(conn *sql.DB) {
    log.Println("Database migration start")

    m, err := migrate.New(
        "file://db/migrations",
        "postgres://user-name:strong-password@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Database migration failed: ", err)
    }

    if err := m.Down(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Database migration(down) failed:", err)
    }

    if err := m.Up(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Database migration(up) failed:", err)
    }

    log.Println("Database migration completed!!!")
}
```

`db/migrations/000_create_table_dummy.up.sql` -

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY (
  user_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPZ,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPZ
);
```

`db/migrations/000_create_table_dummy.down.sql` -

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DUMMY;
```

`docker-compose.yml` for running postgres is -

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: local_pgdb4grpc
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user-name
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strong-password
    volumes:
      - local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4_container4grpc
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user-name@domain-name.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: strong-password
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
  local_pgdata:
  pgadmin-data:
```

When I run the main program I get the below error -

```
./bin/server
18:41:36 Database migration start
18:41:37 Database migration(down) failed: no change
make: *** [Makefile:27: execute] Error 1
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you expecting this to apply all `.down.sql` scripts then all `.up.sql` scripts? (usually you would just call `Up()`). Does your database contain a `schema_migrations` table, if so, what is in it? Anyway you will need to add a check for `err != migrate.ErrNoChange` because this is not really an error in most cases. Note that `master` and `Migrate` are connecting to different databases (you can use `migrate.NewWithDatabaseInstance`, as shown [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4#section-readme), to avoid the second connection).